# What line is defining this hover effect?

Tags: html, css

I have used this tutorial: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

When I hover Webdesign a new menu comes out, and when I hover "HTML", "Webdesign" changes colour to a different grey.So as I move out in the menu, the path I am choosing has another gray-color. What line in the CSS file is defining that? I want to change that gray-color.

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {
    background: #909eab url(bg.png);
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px;
}

nav {
    margin: 100px auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }
        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        }
            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
            color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
        }


    nav ul ul {
        background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
        position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none; 
            border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
        }
            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 15px 40px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #4b545f;
                }

    nav ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
```

EDIT:

HTML-code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>CSS Dropdown Menu</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. We can't check the whole tutorial site .

Comment: It would be really helpful if you put the `HTML` part.

Comment: Could you please add the `html` too?

Comment: please post complete code example, i.e. your html is missing

Comment: Hey, easy on the buttons, people. [S]he's just starting! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its coming from this line.

```
nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try to edit it, it both the Tutorials and Webdesign changes to white: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uyw23c1L/
Is there a way to do this so only the last one will change?

Comment: Use `nav ul ul li:hover` instead of `nav ul li:hover` for you custom CSS.
Keep original CSS as it is and add `nav ul ul li:hover`  and overwrite the CSS there.

Comment: Okey, now I have added and adjusted it, but as I use this in an adapted code I once more cant get it to work: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uyw23c1L/

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code are working on hover:

```
nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        }
```

So make your color changes here so that they get reflected.

Answer (score 0):

**Used to this css**

```
nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        }
```

You can try to this css or html

```css
nav {
 margin: 100px auto; 
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
 display: none;
}

 nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
 }


nav ul {
 background: #efefef; 
 background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 padding: 0 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;  
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
}
 nav ul:after {
  content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
 }

 nav ul li {
  float: left;
 }
  nav ul li:hover {
   background: #4b545f;
   background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
  }
   nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
   }
  
  nav ul li a {
   display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
   color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
  }
   
  
 nav ul ul {
  background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
 }
  nav ul ul li {
   float: none; 
   border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
  }
   nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
   } 
    nav ul ul li a:hover {
     background: #4b545f;
    }
  
 nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
 }
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try to edit it, it both the Tutorials and Webdesign changes to white: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uyw23c1L/
Is there a way to do this so only the last one will change?